# autostartdbpath missing from VBoxManage setproperty

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I am trying to autostart my VM's on a debian box using VirtualBox.  Whenever I issue the command

```
VBoxManage setproperty autostartdbpath /etc/vbox
```

I get the following output.

```
user@dbox:~/VirtualBox VMs/mustang$ VBoxManage setproperty autostartdbpath /etc/vbox     
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 4.1.18_Debian
(C) 2005-2015 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

Usage:

VBoxManage setproperty      machinefolder default|<folder> |
                        vrdeauthlibrary default|<library> |
                        websrvauthlibrary default|null|<library> |
                        vrdeextpack null|<library> |
                        loghistorycount <value>

Syntax error: Invalid parameter 'autostartdbpath'
```

Why is autostartdbpath not an option for VBoxManage?

Debian version

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1
```

VBoxManage version

```
VBoxManage --version
4.1.18_Debianr78361
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for was added in VirtualBox 4.2.0. It doesn't exist in 4.1.18.

To start a virtual machine at boot time, add calls to `VBoxManage startvm` to a startup script: `/etc/rc.local`, an `@reboot` cron job, a SysVinit/upstart/systemd service, or whichever method you prefer.